# How to enter rescue mode (RescueInitramfs) on Debian server?

Tags: linux, debian, grub, busybox, dropbear

I am trying to boot into RescueInitRamfs (https://wiki.debian.org/RescueInitramfs) on my Debian server after configuring DropBear as per https://benediktkr.github.io/ops/2015/05/01/remote-fde.html (mostly).

I have tried updating the kernel boot parameter in file `/etc/default/grub` by setting
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet rescue/enable=true"` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rescue/enable=true"` (as per https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch08s06.en.html), then running `sudo update-grub`. I have verified that the kernel is being booted with this parameter by inspecting `/proc/cmdline`. It seems that this kernel parameter has no effect and the system is booting straight into "normal" (not rescue) mode.

I then tried to boot into rescue mode by setting the kernel parameter `systemd.unit=rescue.target` and now I am unable to SSH in but the server seems to be online as I can ping it.

1. Why is `rescue/enable=true` doing nothing?
2. What is the difference between `rescue/enable=true` and `systemd.unit=rescue.target`?
3. What should I be doing to get this working with DropBear?

UPDATE - to clarify, I only have SSH access. No console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rescue/enable=true` works when booting from Debian installation media only, since only the installer understands that parameter.

`rescue/enable=true` tells the installer to not do a regular installation, and instead begin an automated procedure to look for an existing installation of Debian and mount it ready for chrooting if possible, and just provide a root shell environment if not.

`systemd.unit=rescue.target` tells `systemd`  to start `rescue.target` instead of the normal `graphical.target` or `multi-user.target`. The `rescue.target` will mount all local filesystems normally and will set up network interfaces, but will not start most services (i.e. `sysinit.target` will be executed). In this mode, the system has already transitioned off initramfs, so it seems it's not what you're looking for.

To gain access to the system while it's in initramfs, you'll need to specify one of the `break=` boot options. If you specify just `break`, it will be the same as `break=premount`, i.e. boot process is stopped just before attempting to mount the real root filesystem. The possible `break=` boot options are `top`, `modules`, `premount`, `mount`, `mountroot`, `bottom` and `init`.

You might want to read `/usr/share/doc/dropbear-initramfs/README.initramfs` on your system for more up-to-date instructions on using `dropbear` within initramfs, instead of relying on a document written in 2015 and a proposed-for-deletion Debian Wiki page that's been last modified in 2012...

Comment: Is InitramFs a suitable environment for configuring disk encryption? My plan is to set the break=premount kernel param (/etc/default/grub), reboot server, SSH into InitramFs premount, configure disks, remove break=premount kernal param and hopefully everything will work. Is this a completely ridiculous thing to do or does it make sense?